# Cakephp with Translate Behavior

Tags: cakephp, behavior, translate

I have setted the translate behavior and it work fine, but I need something more.
If I haven't translated the fields, I need that the find() return me fields in default languge (this case eng).
How I could do it?

Answer (score 0):

By default, if cake cannot find the language translations for the given language, it will default to what is set in the application. So this should already be working. Confirm that you have all of the english translations filled out. If this is still not working, you will need to provide some code and examples of what is not working.